# records not recorded in database (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in php but not record something in database (MySQL), but nevertheless, show "Records charged" (registros dados de alta). This code connect in database succesfully. Don´t have errors during debug. I have two files, enter data in form (index.php), and move the data through POST to registracion.php, and record this registers.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario de registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Ingrese sus datos</h2>
        <form action="registracion.php" method="POST">
            <p><label for="nombre">Nombre: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="nombre"></p>
            <p><label for="apellido">Apellido: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="apellido"></p>     
            <p><label for="email">Email: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="email"></p>
            <p><label for="dni">DNI: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="dni"></p>
            <label for="sexo">Sexo: </label><br>                                          
                <select name="sexo" id="ubicacion">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
                    <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                    <option value="M">Masculino</option>      
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                Fecha
            <input type="text" name="dia" size="2">
                <input type="text" name="mes" size="2">
                <input type="text" name="anio" size="4">
                <br>    

            <p><input type="submit" value="Registrarse" name="submit"></p>
            <p><input type="reset" value="Limpiar"></p>
        </form> 
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                $nombre = trim($_POST["nombre"]);
                $apellido = trim($_POST["apellido"]);
                $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
                $sexo = trim($_POST["sexo"]);
                $dni = trim($_POST["dni"]);         
                $dia= trim($_POST["dia"]);
                $mes= trim($_POST["mes"]);
                $anio= trim($_POST["anio"]);
                $response = array();
                if($nombre == "" or $apellido == "" or $dni == "" or $email == "" or $sexo == "" or $dia== 0 or $mes== 0 or $anio== 0)
                    $response[] = "Debes completar todos los campos";
                if((strlen($nombre) < 5)||(strlen($nombre) > 10))
                    $response[] ="El nombre debe tener entre 5 y 10 caracteres";
                if(!(filter_var($nombre, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"))))) 
                    $response[]="Se deben ingresar solo letras";
                if((strlen($apellido) < 5)||(strlen($apellido) > 10))
                    $response[] ="El apellido debe tener entre 5 y 10 caracteres";
                if(!(filter_var($apellido, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options" => array("regexp" => "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"))))) 
                    $response[]="Se deben ingresar solo letras";                
                if(!is_numeric($dni))
                    $response[]="Debe tener solo numeros";
                if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ))
                     "El email no es valido";
                if (!(checkdate($_REQUEST['mes'],$_REQUEST['dia'],$_REQUEST['anio'])))
                    $response[] = "La fecha no es valida";
                if(empty($response)) 
                    echo "<p> Sus datos se han enviado correctamente</p>"; 
                else
                {
                    foreach($response as $r) 
                    echo "Errores: ".$r."<br>"; 
                }
            }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

registracion.php

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario de registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <br /><br />
    <h2>Sus datos son:</h2>
    <?php           
        echo'<br/>';
        if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) 
        {
           $nombre= $_POST['nombre']; 
           echo "$nombre";
        }   
        echo'<br/>';    
        if (isset($_POST['apellido'])) 
        {
           $apellido = $_POST['apellido']; 
           echo "$apellido";
        }
        echo'<br/>';        
        if (isset($_POST['dni'])) 
        {
           $dni = $_POST['dni']; 
            echo "$dni";
        }       
        echo'<br/>';        
        if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
        {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            echo "email";  
        }
        echo'<br/>'; 
        if (isset($_POST['sexo'])) 
        {
           $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
           echo "$sexo";
        }
        echo'<br/>'; 
        if (isset($_POST['dia'])) 
        {
           $dia = $_POST['dia'];
           echo "$dia";
        }
        echo'<br/>'; 
        if (isset($_POST['mes'])) 
        {
           $mes = $_POST['mes'];
           echo "$mes";
        }
        echo'<br/>'; 
        if (isset($_POST['anio'])) 
        {
           $anio = $_POST['anio'];
           echo "$anio";
        }        

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $db = "base";

    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
    $dni=$_POST['dni'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $sexo=$_POST['sexo'];
    $dia=$_POST['dia'];
    $mes=$_POST['mes'];
    $anio=$_POST['anio'];
    $fecha=strtotime($dia.$mes.$anio);

    $enlace = conectarBaseDeDatos($host,$user,$pass,$db);

    if($enlace)
        echo "<br> Conectado exitosamente";

    echo '<br><br>';    

    $cadena = "INSERT INTO cliente ('nombre','apellido','dni','email','sexo','fecha') VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido',$dni,'$email',$sexo,'$fecha')";
    $resultado=ejecutar($cadena,$enlace);

    echo '<br><br>';    



    function conectarBaseDeDatos($host,$user,$pass,$db)
    {
        $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Error al conectarse al servidor");
        mysql_select_db($db) or die("Error al conectarse la base de datos");

        return $link;
    }   

    function ejecutar($cadena,$enlace)
    {
        $consulta = mysql_query($cadena,$enlace);
        $numerofilas = mysql_num_rows($consulta);
        if($numerofilas)
        {
            while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
                echo $fila['id'] . " - " . $fila['nombre'] . " - " . $fila['nombre']." - ".$fila['laboratorio']." - ".$fila['costo']." - ".$fila['venta'] . "<br>";         
        } 
        $registros=mysql_affected_rows();   
        if($registros)
            echo "<br> Registros dados de alta";
        else
            echo "no se pudo dar de alta";  


        return $consulta;           
    }

?>
```

It appear this warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Base de datos\TP 6\ejercicio 3 v1\registracion.php on line 99

Comment: strings need to be quoted in the insert

Comment: And strings need to be escaped - currently you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! And on top of that: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed from PHP. Switch to mysqli or PDO, please.

Comment: I insert quotes in the insert, but don´t work

Comment: I update registracion.php file but show me "1054: Unknown column 'qqqqq' in 'field list' no se pudo dar de alta"  http://pastebin.com/fzgHEXdP